# Im getting a warning in C

Tags: c

I want to check if a date has passed or not but i get a warning form the complier

```
warning: initialization of 'int' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

and as you may see im just starting out in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    strftime(buffer, 80, "%d%m%H%M", timeinfo);             // Get date and time and format it as DDMMHM and store it in buffer
    puts(buffer);                                           // Print date stored in buffer
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    int as = "22051222";                                    // Set an int according to date of the first conditon
    if ( as < buffer ) {                                    // if as < than the date saved in buffer
        printf("22/05/2020 - 12:22 ------ Florian.M\n\n");  // then print this line
    } else {
    printf("22/05/2020 - 12:22 ------ Florian.M>>>\n\n");   // else print this line
    }
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Which is the best way to do this

Comment: `int as = "22051222";` <-- I'm sure `"22051222"` is **not** an `int`

Comment: No, this question could have been avoided if OP would have spent more than 30 seconds re-reading his code

Comment: This question was closed **way** too quickly.  Vote to reopen.

Comment: I voted for a typo, not about *need debugging details*

Comment: @Cid yeah if people vote for different reasons then it gives a faulty message that they all voted for one of them.

Comment: @M.M yep, it's either the majority, either the first reason that wins

Comment: I've rolled back the edit, don't fix your code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
if ( as < buffer )
```

You're comparing `as` which is an `int` with `buffer` which is a character array.  You can't compare these two types like that.

What you can do is make `as` into a string and use `strcmp` to compare them:

```
char as[] = "22051222";
if (strcmp(as,buffer) < 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int as = "22051222";
```

If you want a string, turn this into a char*. If you want an integer, remove the quotation marks.

Comment: I think if i want to get this right so it works i need to start reading and learning properly thank you for your answer friend